# Convert unix timestamp to datetime with milliseconds in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

**Problem**

Converting unix timestamp to datetime while retaining milliseconds.

**Background**

I am receiving unix timestamp in the following format:

- 1584049707

Then I am trying to send it by means of PHP to a column in MySQL that is `datetime(3)` using `TO_TIMESTAMP()`. I have also tried `FROM_UNIXTIME()`, but with the same results.

**SQL**

```
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO assoc_table (timestart, timeend) 
  VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(:timestart), TO_TIMESTAMP(:timeend))
";
```

**Result**

- 2020-03-12 22:42:23.000

For some reason it does not register the milliseconds.

**Desired outcome**

- To get the milliseconds out of the unix timestamp and into the datetime column.

Comment: But your epoch timestamp has no millisecond part in the first place.

Comment: I'm using Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); to get the unix timestamp from JS. Could it be so easy that I need to remove / 1000?

Comment: Where does `TO_TIMESTAMP()` come from? I don't see that in any MySQL documentation?

Comment: Also, if your column is a `DATETIME` type, it expects a value in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fraction]` format

Comment: Why would it register any milliseconds? 1584049707 doesn't contain milliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Epoch timestamps represent then number of *seconds* elapsed since January 1st, 1970; if you want fractional secons, it needs to have a fractional part... which is not the case with the input that you are given to MySQL; this is then reflected in the results that you are getting.

Given an epoch timestamp with a fractional part, `from_unixtime()` works as expected:

```
select from_unixtime(1584049707.123)
```

Returns:

```
2020-03-12 21:48:27.123
```

Note: `datetime(3)` is the relevant format to store such value.

Comment: What exactly do I need to write in JavaScript to get "1584049707.123"? It seems the issue is there. I have tried now() and getTime(), but neither return a fractional part.

Comment: @kexxcream remove `Math.round()`, eg `(Date.now() / 1000).toFixed(3)`

Comment: @Phil That seems to work well, but when I apply `FROM_UNIXTIME(:timestart)` it adds three zeros. The result I get is: `2020-03-12 23:30:45.182000`. The output should be `2020-03-12 23:30:45.182`. How can I remove the last three zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a datetime object with php usign the epoch and then formatting it should work:

```
$epoch = 1584049707;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

if you need to do the conversion on MySQL check this documentation:
https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql

should look like:

```
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval -315619200 second),'%Y-%m-%d-%f');
```

where -315619200 is your epoch